Отображение документов confluence в виде дерева resrtructured text
Я хочу получить в конфлюенс отображение дерева документов, схожее с моей файловой структурой
Структура файлов
- index.rst
- chapter1/
  - index.rst
  - chapter11.rst
- chapter2/
  - index.rst
  - chapter21.rst

index.rst
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   :caption: Содержание:

   chapter1/index
   chapter1/chapter11
   chapter2/index
   chapter2/chapter21

chapter1.rst
================
Глава 1
================

Содержимое Главы 1.

chapter2.rst
================
Глава 2
================

Содержимое Главы 2.

chapter11.rst
================
Глава 11
================

Содержимое Главы 11.

chapter21.rst
================
Глава 21
================

Содержимое Главы 21.

Собираю документ командой
sphinx-build -d confluence path/to/source path/to/temp
ожидаю что будет
Заголовок вашей страницы
  * Глава 1
     * Подглава 1.1
  * Глава 2
     * Подглава 2.1

Но получаю
Заголовок вашей страницы
  * Глава 1
  * Подглава 1.1
  * Глава 2
  * Подглава 2.1


Для решения этого вопроса во вложенных файлах index.rst нужно добавить директиву toctree, и в главном index.rst необходимо указывать ссылку на вложенные index.rst.
